# Simple Rating Star CSS

Tags: html, css, ratingbar

I am trying to build a simple rating system using HTML and CSS. It's a very simple rating bar which consist of 5 stars.

```css
fieldset,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating>label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating>.half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating>label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}

.rating>input:checked~label,

/* show gold star when clicked */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,

/* hover current star */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #FFD700;
}


/* hover previous stars in list */

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,

/* hover current star when changing rating */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label,

/* lighten current selection */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #FFED85;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<fieldset class="rating">

  <input type="radio" id="5star" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label class="full" for="star5" title="Excellent"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4halfstar" name="rating" value="4.5" />
  <label class="half" for="4halfstar" title="Good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4star" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label class="full" for="4star" title="Pretty good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3halfstar" name="rating" value="3.5" />
  <label class="half" for="3halfstar" title="Nice"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3star" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label class="full" for="3star" title="Ok"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2halfstar" name="rating" value="2.5" />
  <label class="half" for="2halfstar" title="Kinda bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2star" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label class="full" for="2star" title="Bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1halfstar" name="rating" value="1.5" />
  <label class="half" for="1halfstar" title="Meh"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1star" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label class="full" for="1star" title="Umm"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="halfstar" name="rating" value="0.5" />
  <label class="half" for="halfstar" title="Worst"></label>

</fieldset>
```

The problem is that I can only select the star up to 4.5 star which is half of the 5th star, what I want is to select the full 5 star. I have included an image of the rating bar below. Help is really appreciated.

[Rating bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwGJQ.jpg)

Comment: input has `id="5star"`, label has `for="star5"` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a typo- needed to change `star5` to `5star`:

```css
fieldset,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating>label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating>.half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating>label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}

.rating>input:checked~label,

/* show gold star when clicked */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,

/* hover current star */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #FFD700;
}


/* hover previous stars in list */

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,

/* hover current star when changing rating */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label,

/* lighten current selection */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #FFED85;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<fieldset class="rating">

  <input type="radio" id="5star" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label class="full" for="5star" title="Excellent"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4halfstar" name="rating" value="4.5" />
  <label class="half" for="4halfstar" title="Good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4star" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label class="full" for="4star" title="Pretty good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3halfstar" name="rating" value="3.5" />
  <label class="half" for="3halfstar" title="Nice"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3star" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label class="full" for="3star" title="Ok"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2halfstar" name="rating" value="2.5" />
  <label class="half" for="2halfstar" title="Kinda bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2star" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label class="full" for="2star" title="Bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1halfstar" name="rating" value="1.5" />
  <label class="half" for="1halfstar" title="Meh"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1star" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label class="full" for="1star" title="Umm"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="halfstar" name="rating" value="0.5" />
  <label class="half" for="halfstar" title="Worst"></label>

</fieldset>
```